# How to create swipeable and clickable cards in android using cardView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cardview

I tried using https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView but could not modify it to create a click functionality.

basically I want to use animate() when clicked on the card but not able to do so.

> Main activity--

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public ArrayList<String> al;
    public ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public int i;

    @BindView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("php");
        al.add("c");
        al.add("python");
        al.add("java");
        al.add("html");
        al.add("c++");
        al.add("css");
        al.add("javascript");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.helloText, al );

        flingContainer.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
                // this is the simplest way to delete an object from the Adapter (/AdapterView)
                Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
                al.remove(0);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                //Do something on the left!
                //You also have access to the original object.
                //If you want to use it just cast it (String) dataObject
                makeToast(MainActivity.this, "Left!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                makeToast(MainActivity.this, "Right!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
                // Ask for more data here
                al.add("XML ".concat(String.valueOf(i)));
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.d("LIST", "notified");
                i++;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
                View view = flingContainer.getSelectedView();
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_right_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent < 0 ? -scrollProgressPercent : 0);
                view.findViewById(R.id.item_swipe_left_indicator).setAlpha(scrollProgressPercent > 0 ? scrollProgressPercent : 0);
            }
        });

        // **Optionally add an OnItemClickListener Need solution for this**
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
ImageView img=findViewbyid(R.id.img);
img.animate().alpha(1f).setduration(2000);   
            }
        });
     }

    static void makeToast(Context ctx, String s){
        Toast.makeText(ctx, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.right)
    public void right() {
        /**
         * Trigger the right event manually.
         */
        flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectRight();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.left)
    public void left() {
        flingContainer.getTopCardListener().selectLeft();
    }

}
```

Comment: please add more details to your question

Comment: Are you certain which language / platform you want to use?